# German word equivalents for 'prison' in a metaphorical sense

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

I was working with this quote

> That is just a fairytale, A vicious stupid fairytale that keeps people in a mental prison.

When I went to interpret it, I got this sentence

> Das ist nur ein Märchen, ein Teufels dumme Märchen, die Menschen in einer psychiatrischen Gefängnis hält.

The part that concerns me is this:

> in einer psychiatrischen Gefängnis

I understand that `Gefängnis` means prison. But the word for mental that I got back was `psychiatric` which actually means `psychiatric`. So putting the two words together might have the context of a facility for people with psychiatric disorders. Which is not what I want. But it is making me wonder if Germans do not use the word `prison` in a metaphoric sense meaning to indicate a form of entrapment.

So would there be suitable words that do not have a direct English equivalent but carry the meaning of being stuck?

Comment: Note that the translation from "vicious" to "Teufels-" works only when "Teufels-" ends up as the first part of a compound. "A vicious fairytale" --> "ein Teufelsmärchen" works. What you wrote doesn't.

Comment: Google translate is not a suitable starting point for a translation.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz well it got the job done. conversation started. Everyone is learning. Common Creative content produced for future members. The question was solved. So I would kindly ask that you not be so judgemental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

> Das ist nur ein Märchen. Ein boshaftes/gemeines, dummes Märchen, das Menschen in gedanklicher Unfreiheit hält / gedankliche Ketten anlegt.

the phrase `psychiatrisches Gefängnis` cannot be used in this context. You might translate the phrase as `mentales/geistiges Gefängnis` but it would still sound slightly awkward.

`Gefängnis` can indeed be used metaphorically (eg. `Ehegefängnis` [*prison of marriage*]), but in general `Ketten` (*[ball] chains*) or `Kerker`(*dungeon*) will be preferable. I don't really know why that is, possibly because a structured and organized penitentiary system as opposed to feudal wantonness has been introduced late in history in German-speaking societies (though this would suggest that the usage pattern in Switzerland should be clearly distinct - I don't know whether it is).

Comment: I agree exept for the use of the word "Kerker" - "Gefängnis" is far more common in the metaphorical sense.

Answer (score 2):

We do use the word `prison` in a metaphorical context sometimes. The problem with your translation is, that you translate `mental` to `psychiatric` which is wrong. I would translate `mental` to the German word `geistig`

Here's how I would translate the whole sentence:

> Das ist nur ein Märchen, ein brutales/grausames dummes Märchen das Menschen in einem geistigen Gefängnis hält.

Or instead of `in einem geistigen Gefängnis hält.` you could say `in ein geistiges Gefängnis sperrt.`

Comment: it's sort of nitpicking for the context does disambiguate, but i don't think that you have a suitable figure of speech. `geistiges Gefängnis` can only be interpreted as Adj + Noun, so `geistig` syntactically refers to `Gefängnis` - but the topic is not a prison that is mental but a prison the mind will find itself inside. A literal German translation might be `Geistesgefängnis`, ie. a compound. The English phrase (afaik) can be parsed either as a compound or Adj + Noun.

Comment: I just edited your sentence from a codeblock (as used on [so]) to a blockquote. This should improve readability. If you don't like it, you can always apply a "rollback" in [revision history](http://german.stackexchange.com/posts/11059/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use *gefangen* together with a mental state or thoughts as in

> in seiner Gedankenwelt gefangen sein
> in Gedankenkreisen gefangen sein

but we would not use the noun *Gefängnis* in this context. A quite common expression for the quote you gave may be

> in den Bann ziehen

where [Bann](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bann) is used figuratively for something that attracts your attention.

Positive:

> Es ist nur ein Märchen, aber ein teuflisch gutes Märchen, das die Leute in seinen Bann zieht.

Negative:

> Es ist nur ein Märchen, aber ein entsetzlich dummes Märchen, das dennoch die Leute in seinen Bann zieht.

Comment: `in den Bann ziehen` expresses focused or excited attention which i doubt is the intended meaning of the phrase which i see in pointing out that people should be kept thinking in certain ways, curtailing imagination, creativity, and freedom.  `teuflisch gut` (*darn well*) actually contradicts the meaning of `stupid` in the original.

Comment: @collapsar: we do not know where the quote is from nor what the intention of this quote may have been. So all is open for speculation - nevertheless I never heard of "geistiges Gefängnis", and would not really know what it is supposed to mean if we had just invented it. However I made an edit to reflect both, positive, and negative connotations.

Comment: @Takkat the quote was made up by me when I wrote [this post](http://www.heutigen.de/auf-was-sie-verloren-konzentrieren-sie-sich-nicht-auf-das-was-sie-gewinnen-konnen/) on my blog. I was reflecting on a few things.

Answer (score -1):

Warum nicht Folgendes?

> Das ist bloss ein Märchen, ein dummes Märchen, das Leute seelisch fesselt.